# visual studio 2010 'System.BadImageFormatException' when adding controls via designer

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, clr

I'm working in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, and I'm having issues with adding certain controls to my Windows Form. I've got two projects, PeakEstimator and PeakEstimatorUI in the same solution. PeakEstimatorUI (my GUI) depends on PeakEstimator (my back end) and everything compiles and runs as expected with the Form and controls I have presently.

I'm running into an issue now however, when I try to add certain controls. TextBoxes, Buttons, Labels, OpenFileDialog controls, and lots of other things work fine, but when I try to add a Chart, LineShape, OvalShape, ReportViewer, ElementHost, etc., I get the following error:

> Failed to create component 'component name'. The error message follows: 'System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)'

I've been searching for similar problems, and most threads I've seen talk about x86 vs x64 issues, but I was under the impression that using clr would handle those things for me. Perhaps I've got a fundamental misunderstanding there.

All the controls I'm having trouble with seem to work fine if I create a new Windows Form project, so I assume it must have something to do with the configuration of my project(s). Any ideas?

This is the first time I've developed any sort of serious GUI or used Visual Studio, and it's the first time I've programmed in Windows in a long time, so please, explain it like I'm 5.

Thanks for your time,

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my initial answer was for C#.

For C++ you'll want to look at /CLRIMAGETYPE.  here's the MSDN that explains how it works and where to set it in VS2010:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31zwwc39(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31zwwc39%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

And here's a screenshot of the properties page.  I'm not sure which value to change to, but you can experiment to see what works for you.

[image]

Comment: Maybe we're using different versions? I don't have a "build" tab in my properties dialogue. I'm still very new to visual studio.

Comment: my initial answer was for C#, sorry.  I revised my answer to be directed towards c++.

Comment: This solution worked. All the controls I was having trouble with are working now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is an error when you try to load a 32 bit DLL into a 64 bit application. Is that possible in your environment?

If you have an external dependency and just have the .DLL file, you can use the Visual Studio Command Prompt to see if it's 32 bit or not: `corflags myReference.dll`. You're looking for the `32BIT` flag. If it's something you have control over, check the project/solution to make sure it's set to build for `AnyCPU` and not `x86` (note: x86 may be required if it does COM interop or uses another 32-bit assembly).

If you're on a 64 bit machine and have a solution that's set to AnyCPU build configuration and try to subsequently load a 32 bit assembly, this exception will be thrown. You can change your solution to build for x86 and that should solve the problem.

Some more resources:

- http://support.dtsearch.com/dts0223.htm
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception.aspx (if you search '64-bit' you'll see this is one of the causes)

Comment: Thanks for answering Jeff. Will switching from anyCPU to x86 have any adverse affects on compatability?

Comment: It will kind of traverse down the chain. That's why I prefer to leave it `AnyCPU` if at all possible. `x86` can use `AnyCPU` assemblies, but not vice-versa. So whatever your startup project is will probably end up having to be `x86`. If this ends up being the right answer, feel free to mark this as the answer so other people will know this question has been answered (unless you're looking for a better answer of course ;)

Comment: BTarb's answer was actually the solution that fixed my issue, so I went with that one as my accepted answer. Thanks for your time though Jeff. You've been very helpful!

Comment: You're welcome! (Wow, I wasn't paying attention and didn't realize this was for C++, the comments I made are for code that is compiled to IL to run on the .NET Framework CLR... so probably isn't applicable for C++ program compiled for the machine. Sorry!)